# Wordpress hook/event/action for when a users updates it's email address

Tags: wordpress

Is there any hook/event/action/method that fires when a user updates it's email address?
I need to do certain actions from my plugin when a user updates it's email address.
Is there a way to check for that from my plugin without altering Wordpress's core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a lot of information out there, but I think your best bet might be writing a custom function and use the [profile_update hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) to compare old data with new. If the current email is different than the old, you've got your solution.

Edit: Link to [WordPress' Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update)